allow camera permission android emulator
I am making an application using Flutter, when doing some unit tests in one of them when it tries to access the camera the dialog to accept the permissions to access the camera appears. Normally this is not a problem but when I run automatic tests it is, because there is no one to accept the permissions.
My question is, is there any way to automatically accept the permissions in the emulator when I install the application to do the tests?
I have read in many places that you can't do this but I don't understand why it is not allowed to do this in an emulator.

After a few weeks I have come to the following solution:

Before launching the tests, I install the bundle in the emulator.
I use the following command to grant the permissions to the app

Command:
adb shell pm grant <package-name> <permission>

Example:
adb shell pm grant com.example.myapp android.permission.CAMERA


Finally, I run the tests

I don't know if it's a good solution, but it works for me, so maybe it works for other people too.
